# Couldn't connect to tor

Tags: configuration

I'm connecting from a company and was ok. Recently I couldn't connect. Here is my log :

> ```
> 1/1/2017 5:31:18 AM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
> 1/1/2017 5:31:18 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:18 AM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:40 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:40 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:40 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:40 AM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:47 AM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:47 AM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50000 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50000 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:48 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:50 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:51 AM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:52 AM.000 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:52 AM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:53 AM.000 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:53 AM.100 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
> 1/1/2017 5:32:47 AM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:32:47 AM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:32:48 AM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
> 1/1/2017 5:33:47 AM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure")
> ```

Comment: `1/1/2017 5:31:52 AM.000 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.` what happened here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not experienced the connection interruption, then the reason is written in your log:

> ```
> 1/1/2017 5:31:53 AM.000 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
> 1/1/2017 5:31:53 AM.100 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
> ```

It can be either a Tor browser or it's plugin - or a side application controlling your Tor instance. Some settings went wrong *or* you've pressed the identity renewal/chain rebuild and it is a bit slow and was not ready to handle incoming client requests yet